# AppCenter not updating

Tags: appcenter, apt

I was hoping you could help me to the right direction. I have seen another post with the exact same issue though it was unanswered.

AppCenter is showing the following components to be updated however it does not update them:

```
4 components with updates:
 • shim boot loader to chain-load signed boot loaders under Secure Boot Version: 15.4-0ubuntu9
 • grub-common GRand Unified Bootloader (common files) Version: 2.02-2ubuntu8.23+elementary27~ubuntu5.1.7.1
 • grub-pc-bin GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS binaries) Version: 2.02-2ubuntu8.23+elementary27~ubuntu5.1.7.1
 • grub2-common GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2) Version: 2.02-2ubuntu8.23+elementary27~ubuntu5.1.7.1
```

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` shows me this:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common shim shim-signed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

And `sudo apt full-upgrade` gives me a warning message and I don't want to break my system, as I'm not a Linux expert would you guys tell me if this will not harm my system?

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  grub-pc-bin mokutil shim
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc shim-signed
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  grub-efi-amd64
The following packages have been kept back:
  grub-common grub-pc-bin grub2-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
  shim
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  shim-signed
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 3 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 60,6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5.662 kB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?]
```

**OS: elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera - Linux 5.4.0-89-generic**

Comment: Possibly related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/diskimage-builder/+bug/1950701

Comment: I don't know if this is any consolation, but I ran `sudo apt dist-upgrade --allow-remove-essential` then `sudo apt install grub-pc` (because I'm pretty sure it's required to add new kernels to the boot menu), and I still have a bootable system. As far as the `shim-signed` package goes, in my case, Secure Boot hadn't been enabled in the first place, and reading [this Debian wiki article](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot#Secure_Boot_limitations) left me convinced that I didn't need/want it. Your situation may be different.

Comment: @TheDudeAbides thank you for taking the time to comment on this, I haven't updated yet because I'm not sure if my system will load after rebooting, I don't think I'm using secure boot (not sure tho) I remember disabling it on the BIOS of this laptop.

Comment: That's a legitimate concern, but if Secure Boot is disabled in the BIOS, I think you can feel more confident about it. As an aside, I find this exact problem you describe (AppCenter failing to do updates on its own without hand-holding, requiring you to run `apt` in a terminal) one of the more frustrating problems with recent versions of elementary OS. This probably needs some attention from the developers. However, that's not going to happen in time to help you, so maybe just go for it? Worse come to worst, reinstalling the boot loader is something you can do with a bootable USB.